# How do I get notified when the user changes the dynamic text size in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I already use the [named font sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.namedsize?view=xamarin-forms) in elements that support them like labels, but I have other views where I calculate the height based on [`Device.GetNamedSize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Device.GetNamedSize?view=xamarin-forms). I bind the view height to a property so in principle everything should layout when the computed size changes, but how do I get notified of the event that the user has changed the accessibility text size? I need to support both Android and iOS.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom Label

```
public class MyLabel :Label
{
   public MyLabel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += MyLabel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MyLabel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName== "FontSize")
        {
            // do some thing you want 
        }
    }
}
```